# Using the Taylor Series of One Function to Approximate for Another Function

Tags: taylor-expansion

The question comes from [this](https://www.nwlehighsd.org/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=1298&dataid=5549&FileName=free%20response%20compiled%20questions-series-solutions.pdf) pdf (2010 part a)

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2} & x \neq 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2} & x = 0 \end{cases}$$
>   The function $f$, defined above, has derivatives of all orders. Let $g$ be the function defined by 
>   $$g(x) = 1 + \int_0^x f(t) dt$$
>   (a) Write the first three nonzero terms and the general term of the Taylor series for $\cos x$ about $x = 0$. Use this series to write the first three nonzero terms and the general term of the Taylor series for $f$ about $x=0$.

I do not understand how to use the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ to write the series for $f$ at $x = 0$. If $f(0) = -1/2$, then wouldn't it make the $f'()$, $f''()$, $f'''()$ of the taylor series $0$ (etc). Wouldn't this make every term after first term of the taylor series $0$?

The solution says

> $$f(x) = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4!} - \frac{x^4}{6!} + \cdots + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \cdots$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In the future, you should type out the question in full instead of linking a PDF. A lot of us are busy, and it takes time to go into the link and find the question you want, especially if it's buried in a long set of exams like this. I'll edit your question this time, but it explains the downvote.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that derivatives are _limits_. Even though $f$ is defined differently at $0$, the derivative still has to remember what $f$ is doing _near_ $0$. But near $0$, $f$ is defined as $(\cos x - 1)/x^2$, and by manipulating the taylor series for $\cos x$ you can recover the formula that you are looking for.

Comment: As an aside, notice the taylor series that you get out by doing formal manipulation _forces_ $f(0) = -1/2$. This is how the person writing the problem knew to define $f$ that way, and knew that doing so would make $f$ have all derivatives. Without the taylor series, it's not at all clear that the function is even continuous!